# Trying to make a simple Lock Screen app work, struggling with Service & Reciever

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, lockscreen

I am struggling to make my basic lockscreen app.starting, the app displays a basic activity screen, with an image view (displaying an image from storage) and a TextView (displaying date & time).On swiping up, the activity goes back. What I am struggling with is, when screen is turned off & turned on, the event receiver should send out this event & my activity should come to foreground again. That's not what's happening. **I am not completely sure how to use my service & broadcastreceiver to achieve this.** Any help would be appreciated please.

My AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kjtest2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>    

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    <receiver 
        android:name="com.example.kjtest2.EventsReciever"
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>      

    <service 
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="com.example.kjtest2.myService"/>        

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.kjtest2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**My receiver**:

```
       import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
       import android.content.Context;
       import android.content.Intent;
       import android.util.Log;

    public class EventsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public boolean wasScreenOn = true;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent recievedIntent) {

        Log.i("Check","[BroadCastReciever] onRecieve()");

        if (recievedIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            wasScreenOn = false;
            Log.i("Check","[BroadCastReciever] Screen went OFF");
        } else if (recievedIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            wasScreenOn = true;
            Log.i("Check","[BroadCastReciever] Screen went ON");

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(recievedIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

My onCreate code in the activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("event", "activity onCreate");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventsReciever.class);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /** REMOVING KEYGUARD RECEIVER **/
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager =   (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();     
    setTime();
    changeImage();
    ImageView img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img2.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Swipe left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
              .show();
            changeImage();
            Log.i("event","onSwipeLeft");
        }
        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            TextView tvDisplayDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date1);
            CustomDigitalClock cdc = (CustomDigitalClock)findViewById(R.id.dc1);
            if (tvDisplayDate.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
                tvDisplayDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cdc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                tvDisplayDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cdc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        @Override           
        public void onSwipeUp() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Swipe up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
              .show();
            MainActivity.this.moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        @Override           
        public void onSwipeDown() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Swipe down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
              .show();
        }
    });
}
```

And finally my service:

```
public class myService extends Service{
private NotificationManager mNM;
private int NOTIFICATION = R.string.local_service_started;
private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
private Messenger outMessenger;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    /** INITIALIZE RECEIVER **/
    //RegisterReciever();
    Log.i("event", "ServiceStarted");
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Display a notification about us starting.  We put an icon in the status bar.
    showNotification();
}
}
```

As of now, the receiver & service aren't starting. I had been able to start them by registering the event dynamically, but I don't think that should be required. Registering the event in manifest should be sufficient for my application, isn't it?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your service is running by including `startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));` statement in your activity `onCreate()`

it is actually required to register receiver programmatically, manifest declaration will not work for `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`, register the receiver instance in service `onCreate()`, unregister in `onDestroy()`

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
 filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
 receiver = new EventsReciever();
 registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Comment: sorry, Why "manifest declaration will not work for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON". Thanks :)